# How do I elegantly override file type detection patterns with more specific patterns

Tags: autocmd, filetype

I have a file in my `~/.vim/ftdetect` directory, which includes configuration such as:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile,BufWritePost .envrc.template set filetype=sh
```

However, I also have the `vim-polyglot` plugin installed (in `~/.vim/pack/packager/start/vim-polyglot/ftdetect/polyglot.vim`, which includes the (less specific) instruction:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.template setlocal filetype=json
```

The loading order appears to ensure that the latter `autocmd` takes priority, which means that files called `.envrc.template` are incorrectly detected as JSON files.

How can I elegantly fix this? Ideally I'd like to keep the `vim-polyglot` plugin installed; and use the `~/.vim/ftdetect` directory as I think it's intended. Is there a way to change the order in which the autocmds are applied?

---

An extract of the output of `:scriptnames` (edited for privacy and with large sections of files in similar/identical paths removed for length) below. Note the relative positions of lines 5 and 96.

```
  1: /etc/xdg/nvim/sysinit.vim
  2: /usr/share/nvim/archlinux.vim
  3: ~/.vim/init.vim
  4: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.vim
  5: ~/.vim/after/ftdetect/all.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/dockerfile.vim
  ...
  8: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin.vim
  9: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/indent.vim
 10: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
 11: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
 12: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
 ...
 17: ~/.vim/plugin/completion.vim
 18: ~/.vim/plugin/diff.vim
 ...
 36: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim
 37: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/health.vim
 ...
 96: ~/.vim/pack/packager/start/vim-polyglot/ftdetect/polyglot.vim
 ...
127: ~/.vim/after/plugin/vim-pencil.vim
128: ~/.vim/after/plugin/vim-polyglot.vim
 ...
```

`'runtimepath'` as per Ben Knoble's question (again, edited for length) is:

```
/Users/user/.config/nvim
...
/Users/user/.config/nvim/pack/packager/start/vim-polyglot
...
/Users/user/.config/nvim/pack/packager/start/ale
/etc/xdg/nvim
/Users/user/.local/share/nvim/site
/usr/local/share/nvim/site
/usr/share/nvim/site
/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.4.3/share/nvim/runtime
/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.4.3/share/nvim/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit
/usr/share/nvim/site/after
/usr/local/share/nvim/site/after
/Users/user/.local/share/nvim/site/after
/etc/xdg/nvim/after
/Users/user/.config/nvim/after
```

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck: the `after` directory exists for exactly this reason. `~/.vim/after` is *usually* the last entry of `'runtimepath'`, so that whatever a user puts there overrides anything before it. Since it can house a full runtime, you can put anything you would put in `~/.vim` in `~/.vim/after`! I use this commonly for `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` to override previous settings (but still allow them to execute).

Long story short, put your custom detector in `~/.vim/after/ftdetect/...` and it should take precedence over polyglot because its autocommand will fire later—thereby overwriting the filetype set in polyglot. Now, this will have some bizarre effects if whatever is happening in polyglot doesn't set `b:undo_ftplugin` properly, because the actual sequence of events will be

1. `setlocal filetype=json`
2. `setlocal filetype=sh`

And if `b:undo_ftplugin` doesn't work right, you might have some stuff leftover from your json filetype scripts.

(Plus, I checked, and `filetype.vim` just does `runtime! ftdetect/*.vim`, which searches in order of `'runtimepath'`.)

---

All of this said, this is why `setfiletype` exists (and plugins should use it).

---

For those in the comments struggling with this approach, please make sure your `runtimepath` has `~/.vim/after` near the end (certainly after anything you want to override). Packages are automatically added in the correct place (*i.e.*, before `~/.vim/after`), but some plugin managers may not know they need to do this (and `set runtimepath+=foo` will put `foo` at the end, potentially overriding `~/.vim/after`).

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this, and unfortunately, I don't think it works how you describe, although you did lead me to another workaround. `filetype.vim` does indeed find all `ftdetect/*.vim` files in `runtimepath`, but it seems that *includes* `~/.vim/after/ftdetect`, and those get read directly after `filetype.vim`, and long before it gets to plugins in `~/.vim/pack` (verified with `:scriptnames`). Moving my `autocmd`s into `~/.vim/after/plugin`, on the other hand, does work. It's a bit of a shame I cannot use the "standard" `ftdetect` directory name, but there you go.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier can you put scriptnames in your Q? It’s odd to me that after isnt last no matter what. Ill check my own later

Comment: Thanks. Edited into question.

Comment: Odd: what about `'runtimepath'`? An easy way to get the listing is `:put =split(&rtp, ',')`

Comment: Thanks again. Edited `'runtimepath'` into question. Incidentally, I have two machines (one OS X, one Linux/Arch) and both are exhibiting the same behavior (they share config).

Comment: @AndrewFerrier to be honest, I’m at a loss... I’ll have to do some digging

Comment: OK, thanks. Don't sweat it too much; I have a workaround for now which is to (ab)use the `after/ftplugin` directory instead. Thanks for all your help anyway.

Comment: I'm wondering if it could be a neovim vs vim thing?

Comment: OK, so for what it's worth, it turns out this is definitely a NeoVim vs Vim thing. It seems that for whatever reason "real" Vim works as expected here. NeoVim instead inserts the path `~/.vim/after/ftdetect` far earlier into the `runtimepath` than it should.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier glad you figured that out; might be worth filing with their devs

Comment: For what it's worth, I think there is something fishy going on with `after/ftdetect` generally in Neovim, have observed some other strange behaviour. For reference, I've opened a [bug](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/12288).

Comment: I'm following exactly the instruction in this answer (using Vim 8.2.2891) and `scriptnames` also show `14: ~/.vim/after/ftdetect/XX.vim` ... `48: ~/.vim/pack/git-plugins/start/XX/ftdetect/XX.vim`. runtimepath remains correct. Either something is wrong with my configuration or the issue happens with Vim too

Comment: Only after/plugin/filetype.vim worked for me with NeoVim.

Comment: @JeffSchwab that's odd. That file isn't "special"—it just gets loaded near the ended of startup (since it's in the `plugin` directory of part of `runtimepath`). Some have observed that NeoVim behaves oddly with `after/ftdetect`. OTOH, without polyglot, I just use `ftdetect` with either `setfiletype` or `set filetype` depending on my needs. Polyglot does too much for me, and contains some known broken things.

Answer (score 3):

I did find an alternative approach, which is to put my `autocmd`s instead in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`. They seem to be evaluated first over `autocmd`s in plugins.

Answer (score 1):

vim-polyglot has addressed this issue.

In commit [Use setf for ambiguous extensions](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/commit/22e8e01c1e7bba0e1aa54255dad21dbb8496dd7a) from Aug 24, 2020, it started converting from `set filetype=...` to the [`setf` command](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%3Asetfiletype), then later commit [Make loading faster for ambiguous extensions without heuristics](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/commit/449bb882486ee69cc63f812120218ed5c17a1ef7) from Sep 29, 2020 expanded the use of `setf` to other extensions such as `.template` for filetype `json`.

This makes it possible for you to override the vim-polyglot selection with an auto-command that uses `set filetype=sh`, such as the one in the question, since `setf` will not override the filetype if it's already set, even if the `setf` happens *after* your auto-command.

See [`:help new-filetype`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype) for more details on how the interactions between `setf` and `set ft=...` work together to allow you to override filetype detection rules installed by external plug-ins.