# Order in runtimepath of Vim packages or similar plug-in managers

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-vim-plug, plugin-vundle, plugin-pathogen, packages

Vim packages work by updating [`'runtimepath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27) to include the top directories of the plug-ins in each package (and also the `after/` directory), but the Vim documentation on [packages](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#packages) isn't absolutely clear on which ordering is used to add the packages into `'runtimepath'`.

It seems plug-ins are added *after* the Vim directory in your home (`~/.vim` or `$HOME/vimfiles` on Windows) and *before* the Vim system-wide runtimes (there's actually two directories for those, `$VIM/vimfiles` and `$VIMRUNTIME`.) The `after/` directories of plug-ins are added *after* the Vim runtimes.

These general guidelines seem intuitive and make sense, since you typically want the files directly in your home to supercede plug-ins (so come as early as possible), then have plug-ins supercede the Vim runtimes (since you might use a plug-in with a richer or more featureful version of what upstream ships) and the `after/` directory exists specifically for when you specifically need to have something as late as possible in `'runtimepath'`.

But: **What are the exact rules used to splice package plug-in directories into `'runtimepath'`?**

What if you changed your `'runtimepath'`, or you're using a non-standard directory for the Vim runtimes?

In the same vein, Vim 8 packages seem to follow on the tracks of [pathogen.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), which started establishing adding plug-in directories to `'runtimepath'` as a way to manage plug-ins, which was later embraced by plug-in managers such as [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) and [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). But it seems none of those is very explicit in documenting the rules for manipulation of `'runtimepath'` either.

So: **What are the rules for splicing `'runtimepath'` used by these popular plug-in managers? Are those the same ones later adopted by Vim packages?**

Comment: This came up in discussion of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60983778/9447571).

Comment: I’m planning to do a dive on this later, including *timing* of when such things happen, since it’s relevant to one colorscheme i maintain and it would be nice to get things written out. Everyone else is free to answer too ofc :)

Comment: Another potentially relevant [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/23248/91) in the context of this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I don't know where to find the "written" rules, I digged into the source code instead. Also note that there are both Vim and Neovim, but it looks that they still share almost the same code in this regard, so the following applies to both.

Also, let me remind that there is rtp-order and load-order, and they are different, as it becomes clear from comparing the output of `:set rtp?` and `:scriptnames`.

So Vim does the following:

1. Execute `:h --cmd` if any
2. Source startup scripts (like `.vimrc` and stuff). Note that `.vimrc` may use `:packloadall` and such to force early plugins load
3. Save a copy of `&rtp`
4. Add plugins directories to `&rtp` (needed to make sure all `autoload`'s are found).
5. Load standard plugins (i.e. `plugin/**/*.vim` from saved `&rtp`, except for `after`)
6. Load user plugins (i.e. `pack/*/start/*` from `&packpath`!)
7. Source `after`-plugins from new (current) `&rtp`

Now you ask about step (4) explicitly. On this step Vim finds every `pack/*/start/*` from `&packpath` and, if it's not yet in `&rtp`, adds it. The relevant code is in function named `add_pack_dir_to_rtp()` found in `src/scriptfile.c` (Vim) or `src/ex_cmds2.c` (Neovim).

As far as I understand, it simply takes the path prefix (before `pack/...` part) and tries to find the first match (like `strncmp()` with the length of the prefix) in the current `&rtp` and put it just after it. Hence all the user plugins paths normally go after `~/.vim` but in reverse order (compared to their natural find-and-load-order). If no match was found then the item is appended to `&rtp` (with respect to `after`).