# Why is my setting of `set softtabstop` in vimrc being clobbered when editing python files?

Tags: vimrc, filetype-python, softtabstop

I am using `vim 8.0.1763` on CentOS 8.1. Here is my `~/.vimrc`

```
" Cool vim plugins : http://vimawesome.com/plugin/fugitive-vim
set number
filetype plugin on  " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754849/vim-syntax-highlighting-does-not-work
syntax on
" Stop annoying line wrapping when pasting
set paste
" Stop annoying line wrapping
set formatoptions-=tc
set ruler
set showmatch
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=0
```

If I open a `*.py` file, and type `:set softtabstop` it returns 4.  If I open another `*.txt` file, the same command returns 0. Clearly this is a python file specific behavior. The only place I can find this being set is in `/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim`

My intuition says that `.vimrc` should be loaded *last*.

**Question**

1. How do I get my settings in my `.vimrc` file to persist when opening `*.py` files?
2. What is the order of operation when loading vim configuration files?

**Note** :

This question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8382/22014).  The [accepted answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8383/22014) of adding

```
augroup python
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python setlocal noet ts=4
augroup end
```

to my `~/.vimrc` does not solve the Question 1 that I pose above. Also the previously previously asked [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8382/22014) does not address my Question 2.

My question is unique in its own right. The accepted answer of my question is unique and not given in the previously asked question. My question should not be closed.

Comment: Re: your edit; I'm not sure why the accepted answer doesn't work for you at a glance; it's possible that the answer should be corrected or that a new answer should be given, but the *question* is still the same. The reason to mark questions as duplicates is so that people searching "python wrong tabstop" in a search engine will end up with one question which (hopefully) provides them with all possible solutions, rather than having that spread out over 2, 3, or more questions. It's to improve the long-term usefulness of the site.

Comment: As for your second "what is the order of operation"-question, a question should really contain just one question rather than two, for the same reasons as mentioned in the previous comment. There are already some questions touching on this ([1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8824/51), [2](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24473/51), [3](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/23248/51)), but they don't fit that question exactly, and unless I missed a question that would make for a good new question.

Comment: The reason the accepted answer doesn't work for you btw is probably because the example only overrides `tabstop=4`, and not `softtabstop=0` as you want; this is just an example and should be adjusted according to personal preference (it won't work for people who want a tabstop of 2 either). I'll add a line to clarify that a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.  I understand that you should only ask 1 question, however my 2 questions are tightly coupled and understanding #2 is important to understanding #1.  Also, I'd like to point out that after searching specific strings that ended up in my question, I did not come across the question you mentioned.  I had distilled the issue more specifically into my vimrc settings being clobbered by something else loaded _after_ my vimrc.  The other question mentioned is much more vague and not posed as clearly

Comment: Perhaps you may view them as the same question, but someone searching for why their vimrc files' settings are getting clobbered and wondering what is loaded afterwards, will not find the information in a question titled "Vim doesn't use the correct indentation in Python files".

Comment: It is more like there are two questions that share an answer together, instead of two identical questions.  Mine is generalizable to _any_ vimrc setting being clobbered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is such a thing in vim called filetype plugin aka `ftplugin`. It is loaded for a filetype after it was read by vim thus overriding your `.vimrc` settings.

for a python check `:e $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim` (line 117):

```
if !exists("g:python_recommended_style") || g:python_recommended_style != 0
    " As suggested by PEP8.
    setlocal expandtab tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
endif
```

You have at least 3 options here:

1. make the `if` statement false by setting `let g:python_recommended_style == 0`
2. override back settings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` -- create the file and add `setlocal whatever` there
3. override back settings in your vimrc using autocommands, for example:

```
augroup my_python_settings | au!
    au Filetype python setlocal softtabstop=1024
augroup END
```

You can check actual order of loaded scripts with `:scriptnames`.

In general see `:h VIMINIT`.